# plot focused spot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the first row of Figure 2 and Figure 3 on page 3 in this paper:

http://www.eng.yale.edu/groberlab/pdf/spot.pdf

So I am really stuck and I can not find my mistake where it went wrong in the equations or definitions. If I leave out all the factor in Eref, I get a plot with circles.

I am really sorry, that this is not a specific Mathematica question, though I hope you can help me and maybe have a look on my notebook.

First some variables:

```
tc = 41.2/180 Pi
tmax = 67.26/180 Pi;
f1 = 2
f = 0.01 f1
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
p = ArcTan[x, y]
c = 300000
n0 = 1
n2 = 1
n3 = 1
n1 = 1.518
na = 1.4
l = 600*10^-9
k0 = 2 Pi/l
o = k0*c
k3 = n3 2 Pi /l
k1 = n1 2 Pi /l
rp = 1
rs = -1
z0 = 0
z = z0 
E0 = 10
xx = UnitVector[3, 1]
yy = UnitVector[3, 2]
w0 := 0.01
f0 := w0/(f Sin[tmax])
```

the intensities i0 and i2 given in (7) and (8):

```
i0[x_, y_, z_] := 
NIntegrate[
NIntegrate[
Cos[t] Sin[t] (rp - rs) BesselJ[0, 
   k3 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) Sin[t] f/
     f1] Exp[(I/2) k3  z  (f/f1)^2 Sin[t]^2] + 
 2 I k1 z0  Cos[t], {t, 0, tc}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
MaxRecursion -> 20], {t, tc, tmax}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20];

i2[x_, y_, z_] := 
NIntegrate[
NIntegrate[
 Cos[t] Sin[t] (rp + rs) BesselJ[2, 
   k3 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
      Sin[t] f/
     f1] Exp[(I/2) k3  z  (f/f1)^2 Sin[t]^2] + 
 2 I k1 z0  Cos[t], {t, 0, tc}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
MaxRecursion -> 20], {t, tc, tmax}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20];
```

then the image field Eref from (6):

```
Eref[x_, y_, z_] := 
Abs[E0 (k3 f^2)/(2 I f1) Exp[- 
    I k3 (z + f1)] [(i0[x, y, z] + 
     i2[x, y, z] Cos[2 ArcTan[x, y]]) xx - 
  i2[x, y, z] Sin[2 ArcTan[x, y]] yy]] Sqrt[n0/n3]

ContourPlot[Eref, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

or with this Eref1 is the reflected field given in (3)

```
 kx := k Sin[t] Cos[p]
ky := k Sin[t] Sin[p]
kz := k Cos[t]
kz1 := (k1 - (kx^2 + ky^2))^(1/2)

mat := {kx^2 kz1 rpk - ky^2 k1 rsk, kx ky (kz1 rpk + k1 rsk), 
kx (kx^2 + ky^2) rpk}

Eref1 := (I f E0 Exp[-I k1 f]/(2 Pi k1^2)) Sqrt[n0/n1] NIntegrate[
NIntegrate[Exp[I (kx x + ky y - kz1 (z - 2 z0))], {kx, 0, 2 Pi},
 PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
MaxRecursion -> 20], {ky, tc, tmax}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
MaxRecursion -> 20] Sqrt[k1/kz1]/(kx^2 + ky^2) mat

ContourPlot[Eref1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: in the first case you need to use `Eref[x, y, z]`. `Eref` alone is not defined. (Of course you need to supply a value for `z` ). It still doesnt work but maybe the error messages will help you.

Comment: the second case similarly `Eref1` being defined with no arguments tries to eval the numeric integrals with symbolic `x,y` ( and a bunch of other undefined symbols `t,k,..` ).  My advice would be to explicitly use functional form for all of your functions.   `ky[k_,t_,p_]:= .. ` for example.

Comment: In your definition of `Eref` you appear to have used square brackets to group terms `[i0[x,y,z] + ...]`. Also the expression contains vectors, if you want the magnitude you need to use `Norm` rather than `Abs`.

Comment: thank you all, I corrected it. Unfortunately it still doesn't work